# MySQL - UPDATE with INNER SELECT

Tags: mysql, select, sql-like

I want to do something like this, but it seems that i just dont can:

```
UPDATE products p2
SET
manufacturer = 
(
SELECT manufacturer
FROM products p, manufacturers m, etc.
WHERE
...other stuff...
p.name LIKE CONCAT('%',m.name,'%')    
AND p.id = p2.id
)
WHERE manufacturer = 0
```

The error is:
    #1093 - You can't specify target table 'p2' for update in FROM clause

The problem is that i have a manufacturer field in the table, but some of the manufactureres name are in the product_name-string instead of the manufacturer field, so i have to get the manufacturer id by the product_name and update the product-table its manufacturer id.

I could do this in two steps, but id like to do this in one.

Comment: AND p.id = p2.id what is p2 here??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A comment regarding this same error at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/subquery-errors.html says, *"MySQL does not allow to UPDATE or DELETE a table's data if you're simultaneously reading that same data with a subquery."*

Comment: I believe you have to rewrite your single statement by a sequence of those, perhaps using [Cursors](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cursors.html).

Answer (score 6):

Try this query -

```
UPDATE products p
  JOIN manufacturers m
    ON LOCATE(p.name, m.name) > 0
SET p.manufacturer = m.id;
```

...but firstly check that records are joined correctly -

```
SELECT * FROM products p
  JOIN manufacturers m
    ON LOCATE(p.name, m.name) > 0 -- bind records in two tables
```

Answer (score 1):

Example on one table that works:

This statement moves all AKTIV-records to DEAKTIV
where already an matching DRAFT-record exists:

```
update table1 fa inner join table1 fe on (fa.datum = fe.datum and fa.firmenid = fe. firmenid and  fe.status = 'DRAFT')
set fa.status = 'DEACTIV'
where fa.firmenid = '+49151506292' and fa.status = 'ACTIV';
```

After executing the statement above i simply updtae the DRAFT-records ton ACTIV and commit

Answer (score 0):

See if this kind of query works for you

```
UPDATE products p2 INNER JOIN manufacturers m ON m.product_id = p2.id AND p2.name LIKE CONCAT('%',m.name,'%') SET manufacturer = YOURVALUE
```

You may have to modify above query as i have written on the basis of my assumption